# Using BeanParam in Jersey Client API

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

In the Jersey API documentation there is an example for POSTing to a service using a Form to encapsulate form parameters:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998").path("resource");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("x", "foo");
form.param("y", "bar");

MyJAXBBean bean =
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
.post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
    MyJAXBBean.class);
```

Instead of using a Form object, I want to use a BeanParam, the same one that is being passed into my method (i.e. my method is just acting as a proxy and re-posting to another service). So something like:

```
@POST
@Path("/CallService")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response callService(@BeanParam final MyBean requestBean) {

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998").path("resource");

MyJAXBBean bean =
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
.post(Entity.entity(requestBean,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
    MyJAXBBean.class);
}
```

When I call this endpoint, I get a `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class MyBean, genericType=class MyBean.
```

MyBean is just a pojo annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and then some fields with `@FormParam("company")`.

Looks like when the post is being created it doesn't then invoke the provider for type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Instead of using a Form object, I want to use a BeanParam"

You can't. Just stick to using the `Form`. The `@BeanParam` is mean strictly for the server side, and it is not even for just form params, it is for all other params also. The point is to combine them on the server side for easy access.

When you try to send the bean on the client. The client looks for a `MessageBodyWriter` that can handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `MyBean`. It will not find one and you will get the error you are currently getting. The `MessageBodyWriter`s available for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` can handle `Form` and `MultivaluedMap`<sup>[**1**]</sup>.

If you really want to send the data as a bean, then send it as `application/json`. Other than that, you are stuck with using `Form` or `MultivaluedMap`

[**1**] - See

- [`FormMultivalueMapProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java)
- [`FormProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormProvider.java)

Comment: That's too bad, seems like a reasonable feature. Maybe next version.